# Printing a parameter to the console

Tags: winapi, x86, nasm, intel

I am trying to print a character received as a parameter by a function.

My function is declared as follows:

```
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   equ -11
NULL                equ 0

global _print
extern _ExitProcess@4, _GetStdHandle@4, _WriteConsoleA@20

section .data
msg                 db 'a', 13, 10, 0
msg.len             equ $ - msg

 section .bss
 dummy               resd 1

 section .text
 _print:
 ;Prologue
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    mov     edx, [ebp + 4]

    push    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call    _GetStdHandle@4

    push    NULL
    push    dummy
    push    1
    push    edx
    push    eax
    call    _WriteConsoleA@20 

;Epilogue
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp

    push    NULL
    call    _ExitProcess@4
```

And my calling function is declared as follows:

```
global _main
extern _print

section .data
msg                 db 'c', 13, 10, 0
msg.len             equ $ - msg

section .text
_main:
;Prologue
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    push    msg
    call    _print

;Epilogue
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
```

I am expecting 'c' as output in my console, but this is not working. The method printing the message works when I pass the variable msg (the one defined as 'a'), to WriteConsole. So I am guessing the problem is in passing the parameter or reading it from the stack.

I am using Nasm to compile, gcc to link & compiling with intel syntax on a windows platform (32bit).

I use these commands to compile and link

```
nasm -fwin32 tiny.asm
nasm -fwin32 tiny_print_char.asm

gcc tiny_print_char.obj tiny.obj -m32 --enable-stdcall-fixup -nostdlib        c:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll -lkernel32
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The `call` instruction pushes the return address onto the stack. After your `push ebp`, you have 8 bytes on the stack, in addition to the `msg` argument. You need to use `mov edx, [ebp + 8]` to retrieve the parameter. Just as your debugger told you.

Comment: In function `print` after the stack prologue is done, isn't `ebp + 0` the saved copy of _EBP_, `ebp + 4` is the return address (pushed by the _CALL_ itself, and `ebp + 8` is the first parameter passed? I don't believe `ebp + 4` is correct way to get the first argument off the stack.

Comment: True, it is probably ebp + 8 to access the first parameter, I tried this but without result, still no message in the console

Comment: So where does the pointer at `[ebp + 8]` point at? Is it not the same as the `msg` parameter?

Comment: How can I find out if [ebp + 8] points to the same address as msg?

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger, like [windbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063.aspx) and you can look at the values of the registers and memory at every instruction.

Comment: Okay, after debugging I found out that: esp points to address: 0x60ff7c right after msg has been pushed by the caller. While ebp points to address: 0x60ff74 when moving [ebp + 8] to edx. This seems correct, however edx contains: 4198400 after this assign. I have no idea if this is correct but it IS the contents of the memory at address: 0x60ff7c right after pushing msg, so there is something wrong with the push

Comment: `4198400` looks like the decimal version of address `0x401000` that seems about right for a variable that is at the beginning of the Data segment (which `msg`) appears to be. Check out the **address** of `msg` in a debugger. I venture to guess it is in fact `0x401000`. If it is then the address in _EDX_ is in fact correct.

Comment: That appears to be correct, I've looked at address: 4198400 and it contains the char! So the address in EDX is correct. But how is it that the print is not working?

Comment: Whats the value in `EAX` after `GetStdHandle` and `WriteConsole`, and is the value correct? Neither function should be returning 0.

Comment: The value of 'EAX' after 'GetStdHandle' is '2656' but after writeConsole it is '0'

Comment: Okay, when I place my _print function in the same assembler file as the function that calls it, it works... I am guessing I am linking the files incorrectly?

Comment: Noone knows. Please provide a [mcve]. Everything else is just a guessing game. With no winners.